# The final cost for uploading and downloading to and from AWS instance (or any other cloud service)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

What are the final costs of uploading and downloading to and from AWS instance?

I know upload is now free of transfer costs, however, when I am doing upload, am I effectively being charged for instance usage (per hour based on instance type)?
Same for download. Am I am effectively being charged transfer cost (9 cent per GB) plus the cost per hour of particular instance usage?

In both cases, lets assume I am just performing upload or download and not using instance for anything else.

Comment: Regarding *"lets assume I am just performing upload or download and not using instance for anything else"*: You will always pay for each hour an EC2 instance exists. It does not matter if you are using it for anything. You have reserved the resources required to operate that server and you pay by the hour for those resources.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding of if you use your EC2 instance or not if your EC2 instance is running it will incur hourly cost except you are using the free tier. So yes you will get charged per hour plus the data transfer cost associated with your resource.

Comment: Do I get charged when instance is stopped (shut down)?

Comment: No you don't get charged hourly if the instance is in stop state